# In SQL how to form an XML output with one of attribute value as XML without <,> encoded

Tags: sql, xml

I am trying for a query which returns and XML output which has one of the attribute value as XML without <, /> encoded.

**Example:**

```
<Event EventLogId="124018" EventCategoryCode="ABC" 
       EventTypeCode="ERROR" 
       xmlObject="<attributes><attribute>A1</attribute></attributes>" />

<Event EventLogId="124019" EventCategoryCode="DEF" 
       EventTypeCode="Warning" 
       xmlObject="<attributes><attribute>A2</attribute></attributes>" />
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT  
    EventLogId  AS EventLogId 
    ,EventCategoryCode AS EventCategoryCode        
    ,EventTypeCode AS EventTypeCode      
    ,CAST(Event.xmlObject AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as xmlObject
FROM 
    EventLog Event (NOLOCK) 
FOR XML AUTO
```

But I am getting this output

```
<Event EventLogId="124018" EventCategoryCode="ABC" 
       EventTypeCode="ERROR" 
       xmlObject="&lt;attributes&gt;&lt;attribute&gt;A1&lt;/attribute&gt;&lt;/attributes&gt;" />

<Event EventLogId="124019" EventCategoryCode="DEF" 
       EventTypeCode="Warning" 
       xmlObject="&lt;attributes&gt;&lt;attribute&gt;A2&lt;/attribute&lt;&lt;/attributes&gt;" />
```

I want `<`, `/>` in place of `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: can't do that-- not legal XML.

Comment: And any XML reader should be able to translate/de-entitize it back for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is not valid to have non-escaped (i.e. not entity encoded) characters in attributes or anywhere in XML.

*To be 100% accurate, before I get lots of comments, you can use the special DATA syntax, but that is not legal in an attribute.  Also it is rare to see this feature used.*

You can read the standard here (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) The base XML standard is actually quite short and should take you less than an hour to read.